# MongoDB geonear and distance conversion

Tags: mongodb-query

I have a geonear query based on 2dsphere (spherical) that returns distances. I am not totally sure about the unit measure returned. Is it meters or radians? Which "multiplier" should I use to get the distances in miles? The answers I've found to this question all differ.

Answer (score 0):

The result is returned in usually in radians

query:

```
db.runCommand( {
   geoNear: "restaurants" ,
   near:  [ -73.93414657, 40.82302903 ],
   spherical: true,

} )
```

will give a result like that:

```
{
"dis" : 0.0001360968348384049,
"obj" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("55cba2476c522cafdb054fee"),
        "location" : {
                "coordinates" : [
                        -73.94387689999999,
                        40.8255961
                ],
                "type" : "Point"
        },
        "name" : "Texas Star Snack Bar"
}
}
```

so in this case distance is in radius, and we need to :

```
1. multiply it by 3963.2 to get distance in miles (in example we have 0.539 M)

2. multiply it by 6371 to get distance in kilometers (in example we have 0.867 km)
```

if you are using 3.2 and have a query with minDistance and maxDistance (by definition in meters) - provided distance is in meters

```
    db.runCommand(
   {
     geoNear: "restaurants",
     near: { type: "Point", coordinates: [ -73.9667, 40.78 ] },
     spherical: true,

     minDistance: 3000,
     maxDistance: 7000
   }
)
```

and example result:

```
{
"dis" : 338.44550608396395,
"obj" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("55cba2476c522cafdb0561eb"),
        "location" : {
                "coordinates" : [
                        -73.9653551,
                        40.7828647
                ],
                "type" : "Point"
        },
        "name" : "(Public Fare) 81St Street And Central Park West (Delacorte Theatre)"
}}
```

there is a nice tutorial about that [here](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/tutorial/geospatial-tutorial/) with datasets - that you cant use for tests.

Answer (score 0):

> The geoNear command and the $geoNear aggregation operator both operate
> in radians when using legacy coordinates, and meters when using
> GeoJSON points.

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v3.0/tutorial/geospatial-tutorial/